# Creating max and mean row in a matrix table php

Tags: php, arrays, html-table, aggregate-functions

I need help in creating a row for max and mean per column(month), I have tried creating a row for max but it is retrieving the max value for the whole year per column.
I also like to know if the approach would be the same if the aggregate functions are to be added as columns, let's say my new matrix table would be using year for rows and month for columns?

Expected Output:
`Day  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | ... | Dec |
 1    | 3.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 5.0 | 1.0 | ... | 1.0 |
 2    | 6.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 6.0 | 1.0 | ... | 1.0 |
 3    | 3.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 4.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 4    | 4.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 3.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 5    | 3.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 6    | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 7    | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | ... | 2.0 |
 8    | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | ... | 1.0 |
 9    | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | ... | 0.0 |
 10   | 4.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | ... | 1.0 |
...
 31   | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 4.0 | 0.0 | 8.0 | ... | 0.0 |
Total |20.0 |12.0 |10.0 |11.0 |10.0 |30.0 | ... |10.0 |
Max   |7.0  |5.0  |4.0  |5.0  |6.0  |11.0 | ... |4.0  |
Mean  |0.64 |0.42 |0.33 |0.35 |0.33 |1.0  | ... |0.32 |`

Code:

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)){
$Station = $row['StationCode'];
$Year = $row['Year'];
$Day = $row['Day'];
$Month = $row['Month'];
$data[$Day][$Month] = $row['D_Rainfall'];
$montharray[] = $row['Month'];
$sumArray =  [];
}
echo '<table class="table-condensed">';
echo '<tr class="text-info"><td><h4>Station Name:</h4>    </td><td>'.$Station.'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr class="text-info"><td><h4>Year:</h4></td><td>'.$Year.'</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table bordered table-condensed">
<thead>         
    <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
 ';
    $montharray = array_unique($montharray);
        foreach($montharray as $name){
             $sumArray[$name] = 0;                   
        echo '<th>' . $name . '</th>';
        }                   
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';           
        foreach($data as $day=>$rainfall){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>'. $day .'</th>'; 
                 foreach($montharray as $name){
                   $maxArray[] = isset($rainfall[$name]) ? $rainfall[$name] : 0 ; //for max 
                   $sumArray[$name] += isset($rainfall[$name]) ? $rainfall[$name] : 0; //for sum
                   $D_rainfall = isset($rainfall[$name]) ? $rainfall[$name] : '-';
                   echo '<td>' . $D_rainfall . '</td>';
                    }
            echo '</tr>';
            }   
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Total</th>';
             foreach($montharray as $name){
                echo '<td>'. $sumArray[$name].'</td>'; // Total Sum per month
                }
        echo '</tr>';   

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Max</th>';
             foreach($montharray as $name){
                echo '<td>'. max($maxArray) .'</td>'; // Max per month
                }
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Mean</th>';
             foreach($montharray as $name){
                echo '<td> total / days in month ??</td>'; // Mean per month
                }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';`
```

Query:
`"SELECT StationCode, Year, Month, Day, D_Rainfall
    FROM Rainfall
    WHERE StationCode = 1
    ORDER BY Year ASC ,Month ASC ,Day ASC"`

Comment: Why the [tag:ms-access] tag?  I removed it.  If it was there for a reason, please re-add it and [edit] your question to explain how Access is invovled.

Comment: Can you post an example array?

Comment: @ashleedawg Oh, I am using ms-access for the database so i included it if the database im using is needed to answer my question.

Comment: @AtaurRahman mostly the arrays we used here are the data from our database, honestly i literally have no idea how to create matrix tables so i just searched and asked for tutorials in the net. and that's how i came up with the code